# Upgradable contract function not accessible

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

We have deployed the smart contract with proxy and using that proxy we have tried to upgrade the contract with some new functions. The contract is compiling and deploying and the upgrade process is completed successfully.

On the other hand we have an APIs using nodejs to access the contract functions.
Using the API we are only able to interact with the functions in the first contract when we try to access the new functions which are added using upgrade contract are accessible through API but it gives error.

Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

I use onlyOwner function.

Error:

Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={"reason":"execution reverted","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","method":"estimateGas","transaction":

We have try to access the new functions which is added using proxy and new contract using web3.js/ethers

We have expect the transaction should be successful and get transaction details

Answer (score -1):

The error you provided shows that there is a problem in estimating gas. You can try the following points to resolve the issue.

1. You can set a higher gas limit to resolve the issue.
2. Check that you are using the address of the newly upgraded contract, not the old one.
3. Check that the account making calls to the new contract is owner.
4. You can manually set the gas limit when sending transaction.